# How to set if else condition on mouse over function

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-cli

I need to change the color of the data(text) in the table column when mouse is pointed over on that text. I don't need to change the color in first column of the table.
I implemented following code. But it doesn't work properly.

```
onmouseover="{{$index==0?this.style.color='black':this.style.color='#f06751'}}"
onmouseout="this.style.color='black'"
```

I am using angualr js.

Comment: Why don't you handle this in CSS itself? Is there a particular reason to use Angular JS?

Comment: I can't figure  out exact way to handle it in CSS.

Comment: So, if you are going to use CSS then check the sample code in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td ng-style="myColour" ng-mouseenter="ng-mouseenter="changeColor(index,true)""></td>
```

Controller.js

```
 $scope.changeColor = function(index,bool) {
     if(bool === true) {
        $scope.myColour = {color: '#c5c2c2'};
    } else if (bool === false) {
        $scope.myColour = {color: 'white'}; //or, whatever the original color is
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default color for the table and then change the color for the required column by adding class / style

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .changeColor:hover {
        color:#f06751;
      }
      .changeColor {
        color: blue;
          cursor:pointer;
      }
      .tab, .tab tr, .tab td, .tab th {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="tab">
      <tr>
        <th>SL No</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="changeColor">Something</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```